# Color changing theme through theme setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am doing one project in which I want to change the theme color, icons based on country. For example, Australia people well enter theme color: red so all icons, and text or background color should get a change to red.

Changing/Loading different CSS is one option but, I want the user will enter color and that color should be pass to CSS file and theme will change.

Is there any way through which I can pass user entered input color code in CSS file?

Comment: I think there's no way to directly access the CSS file but you can use `style.property` method to change the CSS with JS

Answer (score 1):

Using vanilla JavaScript and CSS variables :

```js
function customThemeColors ()
{
  // Get the flags container
  const flags = document.querySelector( '.flags' );
  
  // Reference
  let current = null;  
  
  // Add a click event
  flags.addEventListener( 'click', () => {
    
    // Clicked target
    let target = event.target;
    
    // If target is not a button or if it is the last one clicked return
    if ( target.nodeName !== 'BUTTON' || target === current ) return;
    
    // Get the color from the button attribute
    let color = target.getAttribute( 'data-theme-color' );
    
    // Set the css variable on the whole document
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty( '--custom-theme-color', color );
    
    // Reference to the button clicked
    current = target;
    
  });
}

// Usage example
customThemeColors();
```

```css
/* Using CSS variables */

.color
{
  color: var( --custom-theme-color );
}

.background-color
{
  background-color: var( --custom-theme-color );
}

/* Everything else is not important, it is only for demonstration */

body
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.flags,
.container
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
}

button
{
  width: 75px;
  height: 25px;
}

.container > div
{
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>CSS variables example</div>

<div class="flags">
  <button data-theme-color="#00F">Brazil</button>
  <button data-theme-color="#0F0">Australia</button>
  <button data-theme-color="#F00">Canada</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="color">Color</div>
  <div class="background-color">Background-color</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @sphinxplayer I will do this, I want to take user input color code so, I will try to pass data-theme-color input as user input through variable

Answer (score 0):

No, not unless you generate the CSS file server-side via a controller that accepts a query parameter with the color.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a select tag, that have options with value for example:

```
    <select>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>

</select>
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k2qJ8QbGbAU

heres a video that may help you see clearly what i mean.

Comment: Yes, this option is already in my mind but we want a user to enter the color code as an input and I need to pass that color code through variable in my css

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to replace or add the css class or id of your page body so that you can easily change each and every style of that page. You can use jquery click function. For example: when you click on Australia just use addClass() function on body and add red class. You also need to write css for that red color theme as well.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.australia').on('click', function(){
      ('body').addClass('red');
    })
})
```

If necessary you can also remove previously added class while clicking another one. For more jquery function you can follow https://api.jquery.com.

You also need to add css for above red class like:

```
body.red {
 background-color: #FF0000;
}
body.red p,
body.red span,
body.red h1,
body.red i {
 background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

On that way you change color and theme of your whole page.

Comment: Yes, this option is already in my mind but we want a user to enter the color code as an input and I need to pass that color code through variable in my CSS

Comment: This link may be fruitful to you. Folllow this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color

Comment: Find same example here, this may will help you: https://codepen.io/pen/